# How to re-direct a user when they sign into a web site?

Tags: asp.net

I need to redirect a user to a specific page when they sign into my web site.

In my `Web.Config` file I have:

```
<configuration>
<location path="User_personal_a.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="User1" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

And then when they login I have:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");
                }
                if (UserName.Text.Trim() == "User1")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Client Reports/User_personal_a.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Admin/Dashboard.aspx");
                }
                StatusText.Text = string.Format("Hello {0}!!",
                User.Identity.GetUserName());
                LogoutButton.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                LoginForm.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this unfortunately does not work :-(

Need some help on this please.

Thanks

Comment: can you please be more specific what is not working ?

Comment: Its not redirecting the user the the page, instead it redirects to dashboard page

Comment: I would suggest to not only redirect the user when he logs in but instead to redirect the user anytime he is authenticated.  This will handle the case where a user comes back to your website while still being authenticated.  Could you explain in a more generic way what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a bug / bad design for sure

this part

```
if (UserName.Text.Trim() == "User1")
```

**is always false**, because the text box `UserName` is probably empty - especial before the post back that you have set before reach that line of code.

What you most probably looking for there must be the

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == "User1")
```

but, this is base of your code logic.

Comment: Thanks,  It is working now.  Also thanks for the explanation! :-)